# How to get events from google accounts calendar in android?

Tags: java, android, events, google-calendar-api

I am using this code and getting the events from the calendar and it is working fine but, I want to get the events from google accounts calendar .For example, I want to get the (deepakcando90@gmail.com )google calendar accounts events also? I know it is possible but do not know how to implement it?

my code is ,

```
public static void readCalendarEvent(Context context) throws ParseException {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String dtstart = "dtstart";
        String dtend = "dtend";


        SimpleDateFormat    displayFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");

         stime=displayFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());     

        SimpleDateFormat startFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
        String dateString = startFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());

        long after = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat formatterr = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss MM/dd/yy");
        Calendar endOfDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date dateCCC = formatterr.parse("47:59:59 " + dateString);
        endOfDay.setTime(dateCCC);



        cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), (new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }), "(" + dtstart + ">" + after + " and " + dtend + "<" + endOfDay.getTimeInMillis() + ")", null, "dtstart ASC");
        gCalendar = new ArrayList<GoogleCalendar>();
        try {
            System.out.println("Count=" + cursor.getCount());

            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                System.out.println("the control is just inside of the cursor.count loop");
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    GoogleCalendar googleCalendar = new GoogleCalendar();
                    gCalendar.add(googleCalendar);
                    int calendar_id = cursor.getInt(0);
                    googleCalendar.setCalendar_id(calendar_id);
                    String title = cursor.getString(1);
                    googleCalendar.setTitle(title);
                    String description = cursor.getString(2);
                    googleCalendar.setDescription(description);
                    String dtstart1 = cursor.getString(3);
                    googleCalendar.setDtstart(dtstart1);
                    String dtend1 = cursor.getString(4);
                    googleCalendar.setDtend(dtend1);
                    String eventlocation = cursor.getString(5);
                    googleCalendar.setEventlocation(eventlocation);

                }
            }
        } catch (AssertionError ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any answer or suggestions will be really helpfull to me?

Comment: Have you checked out the Google Calendar API docs at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/?